# CSS Merge background image as one

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to merge these to cell so that it only uses one background image have been trying all day with no success. Is some one could help with is I would greatly appreciate it,

The root domain is http://amalgamite.com so you can see what I'm talking about the two images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>BBQ Grills & Supply</title>
<base href="http://amalgamite.com/" />
<meta name="description" content="BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<meta name="keywords" content= "BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/Bearing Depot/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://amalgamite.com/" rel="canonical" />
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;" class="common-home"> 
 <nav id="top">
  <div class="container"  style="background: url(http://amalgamite.com/pics/Header-Cell-BG.png);">
    <div class="row">

      <div id="logo">
                    <a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=common/home"><div class="HeaderTextLarge">BBQ Grills & Supply</div>
          <br /><div class="HeaderTextSmall">800 Lincoln Blvd. Plainfield PA</div></a>          

      <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right" style="clear:bolth;">
       <ul class="list-inline">

        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=information/contact"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-Top"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">732.563.2225</span></li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/account" title="My Account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">My Account</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right HeaderTextXSmall">
                        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/login">Login</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart" title="Shopping Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Shopping Cart</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout" title="Checkout"><i class="fa fa-share fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Checkout</span></a></li>
      </ul>  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <div class="container"  style="background: url(http://amalgamite.com/pics/Header-Cell-BG.png);">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - $0.00</span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?  Do you want one to overlay the other?  Or are you just looking to remove the hard edge between the two, having one fade into the other?

Comment: Why don t you put the nav into the header and display the image on the background of the header?

Comment: Schiem looking to remove the hard edge between the two

Comment: Laurent Fauvel: I need it as a header BG the body BG will be different

Comment: Well the nav is somewhat part of the header no? So if you move it inside the header and apply the background to the header, you can still apply a different background to the rest of your page/body.

Comment: The hard edge between both is because your image can not be repeated and the bottom one is at a different height than top one, either find a second background image that will fill your need or place both header and nav in the same element with one background image (the header or a div or...).

Comment: I did some re-arranging of your html...see my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the the header below and put it into the last div in the nav bar and set background as transparent

```
  <header>
  <div class="container"  style="background:transparent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - $0.00</span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**------SNIPPET HERE--------------------**

```html
<title>Bearing Depot &amp; Supply</title>
<base href="http://amalgamite.com/" />
<meta name="description" content="BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<meta name="keywords" content= "BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/Bearing Depot/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://amalgamite.com/" rel="canonical" />

<body oncontextmenu="return false;" class="common-home"> 
 <nav id="top">
  <div class="container"  style="background: url(http://amalgamite.com/pics/Header-Cell-BG.png);">
    <div class="row">
            
      <div id="logo">
                    <a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=common/home"><div class="HeaderTextLarge">BBQ Grills & Supply</div>
          <br /><div class="HeaderTextSmall">800 Lincoln Blvd. Plainfield PA</div></a>          
                              
      <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right" style="clear:bolth;">
       <ul class="list-inline">
        
        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=information/contact"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-Top"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">732.563.2225</span></li>
        
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/account" title="My Account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">My Account</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right HeaderTextXSmall">
                        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/login">Login</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart" title="Shopping Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Shopping Cart</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout" title="Checkout"><i class="fa fa-share fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Checkout</span></a></li>
      </ul>  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <header>
  <div class="container"  style="background:transparent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - $0.00</span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to work with the images themselves to have them look more closely the way you want to.

However coding wise, you can have one of the images instead of two. Apply this image to the `background` property of either the `<body>` tag, or a new `<div>` which wraps all the elements you wish to have the background image on.

For example, putting the background image on the `<body>` element only:

1. Remove all `background` attributes from the `.container`, `#top .container` and `#top` (and anywhere else needed).
2. Add `background: url(http://amalgamite.com/pics/Header-Cell-BG.png);` to your `<body>`.

That should help clear up the look and feel.

Disclaimer: **The implementation is 100 percent up to you, get creative!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>BBQ Grills & Supply</title>
<base href="http://amalgamite.com/" />
<meta name="description" content="BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<meta name="keywords" content= "BBQ Grills & Supply" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/Bearing Depot/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://amalgamite.com/" rel="canonical" />
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;" class="common-home"> 


<header style="background: url(http://amalgamite.com/pics/Header-Cell-BG.png);">
<nav id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div id="logo">
                    <a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=common/home"><div class="HeaderTextLarge">BBQ Grills & Supply</div>
          <br /><div class="HeaderTextSmall">800 Lincoln Blvd. Plainfield PA</div></a>          

      <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right" style="clear:bolth;">
       <ul class="list-inline">

        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=information/contact"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-Top"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">732.563.2225</span></li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/account" title="My Account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">My Account</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right HeaderTextXSmall">
                        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=account/login">Login</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart" title="Shopping Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Shopping Cart</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://amalgamite.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout" title="Checkout"><i class="fa fa-share fa-Top"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md HeaderTextXSmall">Checkout</span></a></li>
      </ul>  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"><div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span id="cart-total">0 item(s) - $0.00</span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
      <p class="text-center">Your shopping cart is empty!</p>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
<h2> your content here</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Is it what you are trying to achieve?
On a side note you should put your style in .css file.